# How to write a regex to match .com or .org with a "-" in the domain name

Tags: ruby, regex

How do I write a regex in ruby that will look for a "-" and ".org" or "com" like:

```
some-thing.org
some-thing.org.sg
some-thing.com
some-thing.com.sg
some-thing.com.* (there are too many countries so for now any suffix is fine- I will deal with this problem later )
```

but not:

```
some-thing
some-thing.moc
```

I wrote : /.*-.*(org)?|.*(.com)/i

but it fails to stop "some-thing" or "some-thing.moc" :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Support optional hyphen

I can come with this regex:

```
(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?[a-z0-9-]+\.(com|org)(\.[a-z]{2,3})?
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/cC3sX8/2)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[image]

Keep in mind that I used capturing groups for simplicity, but if you want to avoid capturing the content you can use non capturing groups like this:

```
(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[a-z0-9-]+\.(?:com|org)(?:\.[a-z]{2,3})?
 ^--- Notice "?:" to use non capturing groups
```

Additionally, if you don't want to use protocol and www pattern you can use:

```
[a-z0-9-]+\.(?:com|org)(?:\.[a-z]{2,3})?
```

### Support mandatory hyphen

However, as **[Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill)** pointed in his comment, if you want to ensure you have a hyphen at least, you can use this regex:

```
(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[a-z0-9]+(?:[-][a-z0-9]+)+\.(?:com|org)(?:\.[a-z]{2,3})?
```

Although, this regex can fall in horrible backtracking issues.

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/cC3sX8/5)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[image]

Comment: This doesn't actually check to make sure the domain name part contains a `-`.

Comment: @GregHewgill did you stay at least 2 seconds to read the regex?? what do you think `[a-z-]+` does?

Comment: `[a-z-]+` matches 1 or more letters or dashes. But it doesn't check to *ensure* that a `-` is in the domain name. As far as I can tell, the OP's question wants to identify domain names that have a `-` in the domain name part but *not* match names that do not.

Comment: @GregHewgill fixed, thank you for pointing out that... and sorry the abrupt

Comment: No worries, I know that I've certainly misread my share of questions on SO. :)

Comment: seems ok but the domain name can contain numbers too - sorry if i didnt mention this. I am adding 0-9 to your solution and still testing :)

Comment: He didn't say anything about protocol.  How do you know he isn't using FTP or any of the other various protocols

Comment: Hi @vol7ron yes I know that's why I just used http, OP can easily extend or get rid of protocols. The idea behind my answer is to give OP a hand not to write a perfect answer, so just a simple regex which might help them.

Comment: @purpletech you can add numbers easily by doing `[a-z0-9-]`. However, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

#### [Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/cC3sX8/4)

```
 /[a-zA-Z0-9]-[a-zA-Z0-9]+?\.(?:org|com)\.?/
```

Of course, the above could be simplified depending on how lenient your rules are.  The following is a simpler pattern, but would allow `s0me-th1ng.com-plete` to pass through:

```
 /\w-\w+?\.(?:org|com)\b/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lookahead:

```
^(?=[^.]+-[^.]+)([^.]+\.(?:org|com).*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJ7lS9/1)

Assuming you are looking for the general pattern of `letters-letters` where letters could be Unicode, you can do:

```
^(?=\p{L}+-\p{L}+)([^.]+\.(?:org|com).*)
```

If you want to add digits:

```
^(?=[\p{L}0-9]+-[\p{L}0-9]+)([^.]+\.(?:org|com).*)
```

So that you can match `sòme1-thing.com`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJ7lS9/3)

(Ruby 2.0+ for `\p{L}` I think...)

Answer (score 0):

This may help :

```
/[a-z0-9]+-?[a-z0-9]+\.(org|com)(\.[a-z]+)?/i
```

It matches '-' in the middle optionally, i.e. still matches names without '-'.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I was writing an HTTP server...

... I ended up using the following Regexp:

```
        m = url.match /(([a-z0-9A-Z]+):\/\/)?(([^\/\:]+))?(:([0-9]+))?([^\?\#]*)(\?([^\#]*))?/
        m[1] # => requested_protocol (optional) - i.e. https, http, ws, ftp etc'
        m[4] # => host_name (optional) - i.e. www.my-site.com
        m[6] # => port (optional)
        m[7] #=> encoded URI - i.e. /index.htm
```

If what you are trying to do is validate a host name, you can simply make sure it doesn't contain the few illegal characters (:, /) and contains at least one dot separated string.

If you want to validate only .com or .org (+ country codes), you can do something like this:

```
def is_legit_url?(url)
   allowed_master_domains = %w{com org}
   allowed_country_domains = %w{sg it uk}
   url.match(/[^\/\:]+\.(#{allowed_master_domains.join '|'})(\.#{allowed_country_domains.join '|'})?/i) && true
end
```

* notice that certain countries use .co, i.e. the UK uses www.amazon.co.uk

I would convert the Regexp to a constant, for performance reasons:

```
module MyURLReview
    ALLOWED_MASTER_DOMAINS = %w{com org}
    ALLOWED_COUNTRY_DOMAINS = %w{sg it uk}
    DOMAINS_REGEXP = /[^\/\:]+\.(#{ALLOWED_MASTER_DOMAINS.join '|'})(\.#{ALLOWED_COUNTRY_DOMAINS.join '|'})?/i

    def self.is_legit_url?(url)
       url.match(DOMAINS_REGEXP) && true
    end
end
```

Good Luck!